# Running behat through a PHP CLI script escapes out colour codes

Tags: php, powershell, behat, ansi-colors, ansicon

When I run Behat tests directly from Windows PowerShell, the output is formatted with colour:

[image]

But when I run the php script `runbehat.php` below with the command `php runbehat.php`:

```
<?php
echo system(__DIR__.'/bin/behat --profile local');
```

it produces:

[image]

How can I make it display in colour?

Answer (score 3):

Add the `--colors` option.

From the behat's help that you can show using `-h`:

```
--colors  Force ANSI color in the output. By default color support is
          guessed based on your platform and the output if not specified.
```